# how to format the hint displayed inside a html form field?

Tags: html, forms, format, hint

There was a question previously on how to show hints in a text field (html form field), which clears automatically when the user clicks on the field under consideration. As in, when the field gets focus, the hint displayed inside the form gets cleared without the user having to manually delete the characters.

The solution given (and it works perfectly) -

```
<input onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text" value="search">
```

Now my question is, how do you format the text that is displayed as the hint (in this case "search"). By formatting, i would want it to be in a certain color and font type.

I can do this to the other fields, which do not have this preloaded hint in it, by using css- 
color:#123123; font-family:calibri;

Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily.. They asked how to format the HINT, not how to format any text inside an input box. What if they want the hint "search" to be faded but anything the user types in to be a normal font?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about styling the content (value) of an `input` element.

You can use regular CSS for this:

```
input {
  color:#123123;
  font-family:Calibri;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fxxp4/